# I want to upload excel file on cloud firestore using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to upload excel file in flutter and on button click data in file should be store in cloud firestore. Kindly provide me code as I have no idea in this field.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Firebase Storage instead of Firestore for saving files. You can then store the download link in Firestore.

For upload you can check:

Note: You must first get the absolute path to its on-device location.

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String filePath = '${appDocDir.absolute}/file-to-upload.png';
File file = File(filePath);

try {
  await mountainsRef.putFile(file);
} on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
  // ...
}
```

for further reference [Here is the documentation][1]
[1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files